# User Type Restrictions - Workflow

Tags: laravel

There are several user types in my system and when the jobcosting page is checked(check box is checked) by usertype1  the jobcosting inputs should be disabled for usertype1. Then the usertype2 is suppose to check the jobcosting , when usertype2 checks it jobcosting inputs should be disabled to usertype1 and usertype2. This pattern goes until usertype3

What i have thought is to use gates (to check the usertype) and then in the views to use @can and have the inputs, then disable the inputs one by one accordingly. But the code is getting to ugly to maintain in this way. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel supports Gates and also supports Policies You can think of them as this

Gates are like Closured based Route and Polices are Like Controller Based Route so if your code is getting ugly because of too much gates then why not to use Laravel polices

you can read more about Laravel Polices at Laravel's authorization section, here is the link https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization

Hope this helps.